# add $interval1 and interval2 in time format

Tags: php, codeigniter

i apologize for the last time i didn't questioned properly.it was my first question raised in stackflow.please help me to add $interval1 and interval2 in time format ..i hav spend my whole day trying this .thank u ..

```
public function calculate_time_lap() {
       $formate = "%h:%i";
        $time1 = $this->input->post('time1');

        $time2 = $this->input->post('time2');
        $time3 = $this->input->post('time3');

        $time4 = $this->input->post('time4');


        $datetime1 = date_create($time1);
        $datetime2 = date_create($time2);
        $datetime3 = date_create($time3);
        $datetime4 = date_create($time4);

        $interval1 = date_diff ( $datetime2, $ datetime1);


        $interval2 = date_diff( $datetime4, $datetime3);
     add//  ( $interval=($interval1,$interval2));

       echo $interval->format($formate);
    }
```

Comment: Read the documentation and at least try something: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two add two time together you need to convert them into seconds

```
$date1='3:20:10';
$date2='14:25:10';
$tmstamp = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $tmstamp);
```

Comment: @user2206616 choose it as answer to improve my rep :)